# Browser shows 404 Resource not found error even after pasting php file in htdocs folder in xampp folder

Tags: php, xampp

I have installed xampp and configured the browser to listen to port 8000.I saved the file using a .php extension selecting the all files option while saving and saved it in the htdocs folder.Still when I use localhost\mypage.php it shows the resource not found error.

Comment: You made your browser listen on port 8000? Wow!

Comment: If your server is serving files on port 8000 then you need to be using `localhost:8000`

Comment: I even used that but it doesnt work

Comment: You have other issues then...

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score -1):

Copied the code into notepad and placed the file in htdocs folder and opened it in netbeans and it was working fine.